# Asp.net button still disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a trouble with an ASP.NET form. I have a button on the page disabled and invisible on startup, and I enable it on an event.
Here is the HTML :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveQ37" runat="server" Text="Save and continue" ValidationGroup="save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" CssClass="saveButton" Visible="false" />
```

And the code :

```
                btnSaveQ37.Enabled = true;
                btnSaveQ37.Visible = true;
```

And the button is visible, but still disabled.
Thank you

**Updated:**

Thanks Marcus for the idea, the problem was that it is on a **panel** that was **disabled**.

Comment: what is your problem? you want the button to be enabled or disabled??

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Is the button located on a Panel that is disabled? In which event do you set Enabled = true?

Comment: I want it enabled, but only after the event.

Comment: provide the event details, we need some more details

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the button is located on a Panel that is disabled. This will also disable to controls that are located on it. In order to enable the Button, enable the Panel or move the Button from the Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enabled="false"` And check your `panel` also

```
<asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
```

Comment: I have already tried it, and it does not work, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function callButtonClickEvent() {
        document.getElementById('<%=btnSaveQ37.ClientId %>').click();
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
        <td style="width:30%; text-align:right;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">Drop Down List 1</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30%; text-align:left;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" ></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

**Button  Code**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveQ37" runat="server" Text="Save and continue" ValidationGroup="save" CssClass="saveButton" Visible="false" Enabled="false" /></td>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddl1.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            btnSaveQ37.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveQ37.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            btnSaveQ37.Enabled = false;
            btnSaveQ37.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

This worked well

My guess of problem might be with the **panel** being **disabled** where the **buttons** are **placed**, **try enabling** that too..!!

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddl1.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            pnlButtons.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveQ37.Enabled = true;
            btnSaveQ37.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            pnlButtons.Enabled = false;
            btnSaveQ37.Enabled = false;
            btnSaveQ37.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

where **pnlButtons** is the name of the panel where buttons are placed.